Selenium Python: Unable to interact with visible icon on website despite various methods
I'm using Selenium to interact with a website and I'm encountering an issue with an icon that's not interactable.
This is the icon that i want to click:
enter image description here
The icon is located using the XPath //*[@id='unregUserDropdown'].
enter image description here
I've confirmed that the element is found, as I'm able to print its outerHTML. However, when I try to interact with it using ActionChains, it doesn't respond.
Here is the code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# Setup Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") #options=chrome_options

# Setup Selenium webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open the website
driver.get('https://www.investagrams.com/')  # Replace with your URL

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Wait up to 10 seconds

try:
    # Now find the icon
    icon = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='unregUserDropdown']")))
    print("Icon found!")
    print("Icon HTML: ", icon.get_attribute('outerHTML'))

    # Interact with the icon
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(icon)
    actions.click(icon)
    actions.perform()

except TimeoutException:
    print("Element not found.")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

I used also the click method and result in "Message: element not interactable".
Here is the code:
try:
    # Now find the icon
    icon = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='unregUserDropdown']")))
    print("Icon found!")
    print("Icon HTML: ", icon.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    icon.click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("Element not found.")


I've tried several methods to resolve this issue, including:
Waiting for the element to be visible using WebDriverWait and expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located.
Checking if the element is inside an iframe and switching to it if necessary.
Executing JavaScript to click the element.
Checking if the element is inside a shadow DOM.
Despite these attempts, the icon remains unresponsive. The website I'm working with is 'https://www.investagrams.com/'. I'm using Chrome as my browser and Selenium's Python bindings for automation.
All I need is to click the icon so that a dropdown window will appear and click the sign in.
Does anyone have any suggestions on why the icon might not be interactable and how I can interact with it?

I just changed the browser to Firefox and chenged the X-PATH due to Firefox. Now it is working:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# Setup Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") #options=chrome_options

# Setup Selenium webdriver
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# Open the website
driver.get('https://www.investagrams.com/')  # Replace with your URL

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1)  # Wait up to 1 seconds

try:
    # Now find the icon
    icon = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/nav/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/span/i")))
    print("Icon found!")
    print("Icon HTML: ", icon.get_attribute('outerHTML'))

    # Interact with the icon
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(icon)
    actions.click(icon)
    actions.perform()

except TimeoutException:
    print("Element not found.")

# Close the browser
#driver.quit()


thanks! this works. but do you have any idea why it wont work on chrome?

I think X-PASS address must be changed to :   /html/body/div[5]/nav/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/a/i

so thats why it wont work. can you explain why the xpath you'd given is different from the xpath shown when you inspect the icon?

I use to copy the X-PATH from inspect window by right clicking and choosing "Copy Full XPATH", instead of "Copy XPATH"

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
